# HTML - How can I drag and drop on mobile in a fixed context

Tags: javascript, html, mobile, drag-and-drop

Taking this example

```
<div class="dragable">Div1</div>
<div class="dragable">Div2</div>
<div class="dragable">Div3</div>
<div class="dragable">Div4</div>
```

How can I drag and drop for example the lowest div above the highest div (for example like manually sorting a list) on mobile devices?

I've tried the normal desktop drag and drop approach, but that did not seem to work.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `jQuery` and [`sortable`](http://jqueryui.com/sortable/)

**HTML**

```
<p>
    Drag and drop the items below
</p>

<div class="sorted-divs">
   <div class="sortable">Item 1</div>
   <div class="sortable">Item 2</div>
   <div class="sortable">Item 3</div>
   <div class="sortable">Item 4</div>
</div>
```

**jQuery**

```
$(".sorted-divs").sortable();
```

**CSS**

```
.sortable {
    padding: 20px;
    border: 1px solid black;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/8q96gtj5/

Comment: thank you, but this doesn't seem to work on mobile browsers. But thanks to you I found this guide making sortable possible on mobile: http://forresst.github.io/2012/06/22/Make-a-list-jQuery-Mobile-sortable-by-drag-and-drop/